# ASP.NET LINQ MULTIPLE OR IN WHERE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, where-clause

I have following code in asp.net core using multiple or in where statement. it always propmt error saying "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   lambda_method"

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    mTickets = from mt in mTickets
               where  
               (mt.TicketServiceFullNo.Contains(searchString))  || (mt.DeviceNo.Contains(searchString)) select mt;

}
return View(await mTickets.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
```

However, If i just use one or condition in where. it will work. I have no idea why. Please help. thanks

this will work

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    mTickets = from mt in mTickets
               where  
               (mt.TicketServiceFullNo.Contains(searchString))  select mt;

}
return View(await mTickets.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
```

Comment: It would suggest that `mt.DeviceNo` is null.

Comment: @ChrisF it's definitely `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certain that `mt.DeviceNo` is null.

You'll need to replace:

```
(mt.DeviceNo.Contains(searchString))
```

with

```
(mt.DeviceNo != null && mt.DeviceNo.Contains(searchString))
```

or

```
(mt.DeviceNo?.Contains(searchString))
```

if you're using C# 6.0